# Set openejb javaagent in code?

Tags: eclipse, maven, integration-testing, openjpa, openejb

I'm currently writing integration tests for a Java EE application and use openejb/openjpa. 
But as I'm using CMP I have to use a javaagent to enhance my classes. In maven I can configure my surefire plugin to do this enhancement, or better set the agent as vm parameter to the test.

But as I'm currently developing I like to run my tests quite often in eclipse. But there I don't want to set the agent all the time via

```
java -javaagent:openejb-javaagent-4.6.0.jar _\[other params...](other-params....html)
```

Does someone have a useful solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing in Eclipse purposes, I always create a variable that can be used in the VM arguments section of your Run Configuration. This way all you need to specify is something like `${agent}` (or whatever you call it) rather than the full javaagent string.

Comment: Thanks Rick. It's also the only solution I see so far.

Answer (score -1):

Mhh but not sure, looking at my properties, my classes should be enhanced at runtime:

```
@Before
public void startupContainer() throws NamingException {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings", "buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)");
    p.put("openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary", "hsql(SupportsSelectForUpdate=true)");
    p.put("openejb.embedded.initialcontext.close", "destroy");
    p.put("openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses", "supported");
    p.put("openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent", "true");
    p.put("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", "0");
    p.put("openejb.log.factory", "slf4j");

    ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(p);
}
```

Comment: Please don't do that! openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses is disabled by default because it has a number of bugs and it will do nothing but cause headaches.

Comment: It not productive code, it's just for integration testing a jboss application

Comment: That means that you're testing different code paths than what you are using in production.

Comment: Yes, but there are a lot of tests, we are using Junit-Tests for TDD, openejb/openjpa for integration tests, running while packaging the application and every night a system test against nightly build version installed on a jboss.

Comment: I'm just warning that you will encounter bugs with RuntimeUnenhancedClasses and the solution to those bugs is to use a different enhancement method.